# Paramaterization with user defined functions, KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I would like to add a variable into a function in KQL as in the following. Any idea how to do it? I tried a str_concat() but that threw an error message. Some other ideas? This function should return the regex pattern inside the function, which in this case is just the word after the one specified in X.

```
let MyFunction = (X: string, arg1: string){extract("{X}\\s([^\\s]+", 1, Y)};
datatable(Num:int, Message: string)[
1, "Ye who in rhymes dispersed the echoes hear",
2, "Of those sad sighs with which my heart I fed",
3, "When early youth my mazy wanderings led",
4, "Fondly different from what I now appear"]
extend 
My = MyFunction("my", Message),
Preposition = MyFunction("[Of|in|from]", Message)
```

Comment: to clarify your questions, please provide the expected output for the input that you've provided

Comment: I would like the output to return whatever regex is added inside the function which is in this case should be the next word. The key is I would like to add a parameter to a KQL function.

Comment: you could try to be more clear by providing the actual output - just like you provided the actual input. a verbal description (as you provided in your first comment) doesn't go as far

Comment: I strongly recommend that you'll work with the ADX documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalarfunctions as well as the relevant regex documentation https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax. Some regex tutorials might also come handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use verbatim string (`@"..."`) so there will be no need for double escaping (`\\`)
2. a capture group (the part that you want to extract) is defined by brackets (`(...)`)
3. The regex OR operator `|` should be used like `X|Y|Z`, `[]` is used to define set of characters.
   By using `[Of|in|from]` you basically defined a set of characters that includes the characters `O`, `f`, `|`, `i`, `n`, `r`, `o` & `m`
4. `(?:...)` to separate the argument from the text to it's right, but avoid treating it as a capture group

---

```
let MyFunction = (X: string, Y: string){extract(strcat("(?i:",X, @")\s+(\S+)"), 1, Y)};
datatable(Num:int, Message: string)[
1, "Ye who in rhymes dispersed the echoes hear",
2, "Of those sad sighs with which my heart I fed",
3, "When early youth my mazy wanderings led",
4, "Fondly different from what I now appear"]
| extend My = MyFunction("my", Message), Preposition = MyFunction("of|in|from", Message)
```

| Num | Message | My | Preposition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ye who in rhymes dispersed the echoes hear |  | rhymes |
| 2 | Of those sad sighs with which my heart I fed | heart | those |
| 3 | When early youth my mazy wanderings led | mazy |  |
| 4 | Fondly different from what I now appear |  | what |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02QP0/DMBDF90j5Dk%20eHDULf6YiBFMlhgISA60og4kvtaXEjmxXwVC%20O5cCpfJin3/v3d3rKGGZFzvXJOsdriFXc8QUrNvWWP9dq096T0E1SfK7UUkKeWPnol7VuBXVJs7k5mlWiarGGauqr6uy0CrxeetI3u/6uXWpxpJiVFs6mr6UBeNiTRiNh3UIJvcUoW0cKETSSIZAjfFcNKSCqMvinBUPLf/4SIhKI9qtiRhtMmxjG4M%20H%20CEO7SkJ80Fa54NOXC5y8h%20lw5Yrz4yRuU0TfNEdD/4JeML7zSj2rYtBXIJbfA9N1CTrfMj1DBME72WxR4cDjnNOXJ%20/2FK0Wdx3JqzeQw0%20Gh/gz4Ffbu3bj%201OBF8A1sPdr%20bAQAA)

Comment: based on my (limited) understanding of the OP's description, you may want to replace the function implementation with `let MyFunction = (X: string, Y: string) { extract(strcat("(", X, @")\s+(\w+)"), 2, Y) };` - so that the output is what comes _after_ the `X` argument, and not the `X` argument itself

Comment: @YoniL. Yep, you're right. Fixing it